# Simple C# program appears to be skipping code without reason

Tags: c#

I had my A-Level AQA Computing exam this morning, and one of the programming questions confused me when my code didn't run lines of code for an unknown reason. I tried recreating it at home to see if it was a one off error for some reason, but it results in the same strange outcome.

The question was asking to write a program using some given pseudocode, this is as close as I can remember it. The program in question was designed to take a two digit number and either;
1) add the two digits, then add the two digits of the result until there was only a one digit number left
or
2) Multiply the two digits, and keep doing so until there is only a one digit number left. I can't remember the name of this process but you get the idea. (e.g 77 -> 7+7 = 14, 1+4 = 5. The answer would be 5 in 2 turns/cycles.)

Here is the code;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int value;
        string mode;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value: ");
        value = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the mode (a or m): ");
        mode = Console.ReadLine();
        while (value > 9)
        {
            if (mode == "a")
            {
                value = (value / 10) + (value % 10);
            }
            else
            {
                value = (value / 10) * (value % 10);
            }
            count += 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After " + count + " turns, the value is " + value);
    }
}
```

So it appears to be fine, but when I run it with a test value of 45 for example, this is the output;

```
Please enter a value:
45
Please enter the mode (a or m):
After 2 turns, the value is 0
```

This all happens without giving the user chance to enter a mode.

At first it appeared that the code was jumping straight to the while loop after the value was assigned to be bigger than 9. While this confused me I attempted a fix by assigning the users input to a different value (tempvalue), and then assigning that to value after they had selected a mode. However the same happened.

I feel like the solution is going to be something really simple and a stupid mistake that I haven't spotted, but I can't find any errors or possible causes anywhere.

This is driving me insane!! Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

DISCLAIMER: This is not me trying to cheat my exam, the exam is over and all work is in so this would not be possible. I am just really curious as to what I had done wrong for this to happen and would be interested to know the solution.

Comment: `while (value > 9)` shouldn't this be `while (count > 9)`?

Comment: No, because we are repeating this process until the value left is only a one digit number, so anything bigger than 9 has to be a two digit number. hence the Value > 9. Sorry if i was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that [`Console.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only reads **one character** (if available). `Console.ReadLine()` waits for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (or `\n`).

So if you type `45` end hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `4` is stored in `value` and `5` is written to `mode` without further waiting for the user.

So change the `Console.Read()` to `Console.ReadLine()`, too. That should solve your problem.

But `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`. You need to convert this to an `int`, for example like that:

```
int value;
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse(input, out value) || value < 10 || value > 99)
{
   Console.WriteLine("This was not a two digit number!");
   return;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for your clear and concise answer. This makes sense now knowing the difference between 'Read' and 'ReadLine'. Judging from error messages I assumed one read as a string and the other read as an integer

Answer (score 6):

You're using `Console.Read` for the number, instead of `ReadLine`. [`Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) only reads a single character and not until the next line break (as `ReadLine` does). So when entering `45↵` what you get returned is just the `4` and the next call to `ReadLine` will get the `5`.

What's more, `value` will be the Unicode code point of the character `4`, which is 52. So you should probably change that line to

```
value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This then solves both problems (or add error handling to taste, if necessary).

Comment: Yep, better don't just parse without checking the input first. Use TryParse and provide a meaningful error message.

Comment: @marsze: Considering it was a programming assignment in an exam I'd say the focus was more on correctness of the basic algorithm and grasp of the necessary control structures in C# than on error handling and providing a nice user experience. When I graded student assignments I definitely didn't care about the latter, unless the task explicitly called for it.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried ReadLine() but was using a more complicated Convert.ToInt32(...) infront of it which was causing more errors. This makes sense now.

Comment: @Ben: Just as a helpful hint, looking at the values in your variables (e.g. by printing them just to verify) can be very helpful in figuring out _where_ things to wrong. E.g. you suspected lines in your algorithm being skipped, but you didn't question the validity of the input that went into the algorithm, already discarding the actual problem by mistake. Debugging and finding errors can be a bit of an art sometimes, but questioning assumptions about what works and where it goes wrong often goes a long way in spotting the problem.

Comment: @Joey: This is very true, I suppose in the time pressure of the exam I missed important steps of debugging I usually wouldn't if I weren't concentrating on the time allocated. I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: @Joey @Ben That's absolutely true. It's okay under the pressure of an exam. But since it's also about learning and improving, I wanted to mention it. And even a short comment `// todo add error handling` might gain some bonus points.

Answer (score 2):

[Console.Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads one character '4' and then continues.
[Console.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) reads the rest of the line, which is '5'.

So if you change .Read() into .ReadLine() that will help.

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense now, having only been taught what Console.ReadLine() does and not Console.Read(), i assumed from the error messages that it read as a integer straight away.

Comment: No probs. Always read the documentation before using a new function. :-)